# Angular2 update object array as per checkbox's selected values

Tags: angular

I have an array like following:

```js
hobbies: any= [
    {'hobby': 'Sport', 'selected': false},
    {'hobby': 'Music', 'selected': false},
    {'hobby': 'Reading', 'selected': false},
    {'hobby': 'Travelling', 'selected': false},
    {'hobby': 'Movies', 'selected': false},
    {'hobby': 'Cooking', 'selected': false},
]
```

I iterate over this array in my template:

```html
<span style="float: left; width: 100px;"><h5>Hobbies</h5></span>
<div class="mdl-grid">
    <div *ngFor="let chunk of hobbies | chunks: 2" class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
        <label *ngFor="let hobby of chunk | values" #checkbox class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" [value]="hobby" 
            [(ngModel)]="hobby.selected" (change)="populateTest(hobby, $event.target.checked)" class="mdl-checkbox__input">
            <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">{{hobby.hobby}}</span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is: whichever values user checks those objects should accordingly be updated in `hobbbies[]` array (right now I simply push them into another array).

If any values are already marked as `selected:true` in `hobbies[]`, then checkmarks should already be shown in my template.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
<div *ngFor="let hobby of hobbies" class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
    <label #checkbox class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" [value]="hobby.hobby" 
        [(ngModel)]="hobby.selected" class="mdl-checkbox__input"
         (change)='consoleHobbies()'>
        <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">{{hobby.hobby}}</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Check value on change :

Component side :

```
consoleHobbies()
{
   console.log(this.hobbies);
}
```

---

Some of the Angular2 version updates doesn't support above code , try to run this

```
<div *ngFor="let hobby of hobbies; let j = index;" class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
<label #checkbox class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" [checked]='hobbies[j].selected' (change)='hobbies[j].selected = $event.target.checked' />
    <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">{{hobby.hobby}}</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Okay, and how can I check the latest state of hobbies[]? at each click perhaps for cross checking purpose?

Comment: onchange set function which can console the hobbies , so you can check it on each check/uncheck

Comment: great! this works perfect. The only thing is: If I modify my original hobbies[] array with some values for selected as true, it do not reflect in template? I thought those fields would be marked checked by default.

Comment: No it will reflect those in template side.

Comment: why do you use `(change)` and not `(ngModelChange)`, no need to bind `value` to `hobby`, neither...

Comment: We can do this many ways , it depends on the developer or methods , how one like to implement it. :)

Comment: @Nitish " If I modify my original hobbies[] array with some values for selected as true" how do you modify it. `this.array=[]`, `this.array[0]= newValue`, `this.array[0].selected=true` ?

Comment: no, e.g. `hobbies: any= [
  {'hobby': 'Sport', selected: false},
  {'hobby': 'Music', selected: true},..
 ]` and in this case I expected Music to be checked by default, but somehow it is not

Comment: @VivekDoshi yes, but while change might work for checkbox, it might not work for text if there is no blur event and how would it work for custom input ? It is a better practice to listen to the `somePropertyChange` event than on direct DOM events for such a thing.

Comment: Even I thought that's logically correct- making `selected:true` would reflect in template, but it is somehow not. It needs any upgradeElement?

Comment: @VivekDoshi Any reason there to remove chunks and values? It gave me unexpected closing tag "li" error

Comment: nope not any reason , just for code simplicity , nothig else , so I can test code fast and update you.

Comment: No this gives me `Template parse errors: Unexpected closing tag "li"`

Comment: @Nitish , that might be some other error , there is no li tag in our code

Comment: @VivekDoshi Yes I figured out: closing div was missing in your answer, actually my mistake, I should have seen that. This answer works and I can see checkmarks but this broke style. upgradeElement didn't work I guess. If you know why could that happen, kindly tell. Or else I will anyway accept the answer. It is throwing: `Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`

Comment: It worked. Thanks for all the communication and your answer!